# Eliminate xy term of conic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

For the following problem, I am trying to eliminate xy, and I've tried numerous times to solve if with no luck. I need to find the general form of the equation rotated to eliminate the xy term.

$ 3x^2+3\sqrt{3}xy+6y^2-11=0 $

When I've tried to solve it, I got the general form to be the following:

$ (15/2)x^2 + (3/2)y^2 - 11 = 0 $

This didn't seem right. When I've tried solving it, I've been able to get A' to be 3/2, 15/2 and 9/2, and vice versa for C'.

I only need to see how to get A' correctly, and then I should be able to get C' and finish the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is that a suitable rotation of the form $$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix}$$ will eliminate the $xy$ term.  Substituting and solving for the condition $x'y' = 0$ gives $\tan 2\theta = \frac{B}{C-A}$.  Therefore, evaluating the relationship for a specific set of coefficients gives you the desired angle $\theta$, from which you can calculate the transformation required.

Comment: Would $\theta$ be $pi/6$ or $pi/3$? I've tried both with no luck.

Comment: You would get $\theta = \pi/6$, from which the desired transformation is $$x = \tfrac{1}{2}(\sqrt{3}x'+y'), \quad y = \tfrac{1}{2}(\sqrt{3}y' - x').$$  Substituting this directly into the equation gives $$\tfrac{3}{2}x^2 + \tfrac{15}{2}y^2 - 11 = 0.$$  Notice that the other choice of angle, $\theta = -\pi/3$, would give $$\tfrac{15}{2}x^2 + \tfrac{3}{2}y^2 - 11 = 0,$$ which is also admissible--it simply depends on if you want the longer axis to be parallel to the $x$-axis or $y$-axis.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. The final answer I got was $(3/22)x^2 + (15/22)y^2 = 1$. This didn't seem correct since there were numbers on the top of the fraction. Am I done, or do I need to go further?

Comment: I don't know what else you want to do with this result.  If all you want is to rotate the ellipse to eliminate the $xy$ term, then you're done.

Comment: I'm supposed to put it into standard form, and then graph it.

Comment: Okay--if you put it into standard form, bear in mind that it is "standard" **in the transformed $(x',y')$ coordinate plane**, not in the $(x,y)$ plane.  What I *should* have written in my earlier comment was $$\tfrac{3}{2}(x')^2 + \tfrac{15}{2}(y')^2 - 11 = 0,$$ but I was being sloppy.  Therefore, when graphing this conic in the $(x,y)$ plane, you need to superimpose the appropriate rotated $(x',y')$ coordinate axes, and plot the curve with respect to those axes, to get the correct picture for the original coordinates.  How to determine the correct angle is an exercise I leave to you.

Comment: Right, I got it from here. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the rotation matrix $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @John No.  Switching the sign only means that you're changing the direction of rotation.  Note here that usual way of writing the transformation is $(x',y') = R(x,y)$, but in my response I wrote $(x,y) = R^{-1}(x,y)$.  Editing my post as you have done results in an answer inconsistent with my comments.  Don't do that unless you are **certain** you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use the formulæ for rotating through an angle $\theta$, where $\tan{2\theta}={{3\sqrt 3}\over{3-6}}$.